# 504 gateway timeout on hitting an endpoint

Tags: python, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am currently hitting an endpoint which returns a JSON response. But sometimes when the computation time is large, its giving an **504 gateway timeout error** . below is my code snippet

**Python Code**

```
import json, requests
ans = requests.get(url).text
card_data = json.loads(ans)
print(card_data) # this is where response gets stored
```

**Respone status text**

```
'<html>\r\n<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

[image]

I am also wondering **is there a way to configure nginx settings to increase the timeout** when endpoint is hit. (I have control of the server)

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Nginx` as a proxy server, you can increase the `timeout` in the config file.

```
server {
...
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
...
}
```

But don't forget to restart the `Nginx` server.